# is there any way to reload app with button is pressed in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

My drawer items like login user name doesn't get refreshed when presses logout...but when i save my code in visual studio code then app rebuilt and it shows drawer items updated...I want to do it when a user press button in drawer items the whole app should reload automatically.I make react native app using expo.
tried react-native-restart

Comment: What was the problem with react-native-restart?

Comment: null is not an object(evaluating'_reactNativeRestart.default.Restart')

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when your program performs login or logout, you should update the login/logout text and call `setState()` in your drawer component to re-render it. In case your drawer is using `FlatList`, or some `PureComponent`, you can only re-render it via update props.

For more details, you should provide more code so we can take a look.